# How can I give constraints some margin from the center of superView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I am using auto layout. I have one UIView that takes place at 20px margin from the center of the superview.

Right now I have given the Top Space to superview that i have make in the iPhone 6+ Xib. but when i run in the iPhone 4 simulator it goes to too much down.

Any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the view to be placed relative to the center of the superview, you should be using centerX and/or centerY constraints, not a constraint to the top of the superview. In IB, if you choose the "Vertical Center in Container" constraint to center the view vertically, you can edit that constraint to change its constant value which will offset the view from the center by whatever number you choose.