# ViewController's content is pushed down by navigation controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am setting up a login page in my app and decided to add a navigation bar to display an image/logo. However, after I added this navigation bar and ran my code in the simulator the content of my view is being pushed down. I have attached pictures to show the difference between the interface builder and the simulator. All of my constraints are related to the super view and my view encompasses the whole screen.

[interface builder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYDye.png)

[simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dGUi.jpg)

Comment: You probably don't have a bottom constraint, and the simulator's screen size looks smaller than the storyboard. Instead, you should constrain all the controls (header, text fields, buttons, everything) in its own `UIView`, then have a center X and Y constraint for that big `UIView`.

Comment: @aheze I have it currently constrained in a stack view with center X and Y constraints for the stack view. Is there something else I should be doing? All of the views not in the stack view are constrained in regards to the stack view as well.

Comment: Ok... so you want to move everything up? You can just offset the center Y constraint a bit https://stackoverflow.com/a/26194393/14351818

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow the steps :-

- add a new view inside the main view
- insert all elements in that 2nd view
- give the constrain to 2nd view (if possible then give static height and width)
- give constrain to all elements inside of 2nd view
- `must give 2nd view center x,y constrains`

i hope it will work for you ...!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes back here later:

All of the above answers work in their cases, however the issue for me was that I had "under opaque bars" in my storyboard unchecked which caused the view to display lower than it should.